# Make apache2 to serve files with query string like names

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have a couple of files named like "index.php?page=1", "news?id=1". How can I set up apache to send exactly these files with queries like "http://site.com/index.php?page=1", "http://site.com/news?id=1" etc.
I tried .htaccess rules

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the special characters `?` and `=` in the URL that's used for the request.

For example, if your file is called `strange.php?plop=1`, then, your URL must be :

```
http://tests/temp/strange.php%3Fplop%3D1
```

In PHP, this can be done using the [`urlencode()`](http://fr.php.net/urlencode) function.

---

**Edit after the comment :** in this case *(which is really not good... )*, a solution might be to use a rewrite rule like this one :

```
RewriteRule .*    temp.php
```

This will redirect **everything** to `temp.php`.

There, you might be able to work with something in [**`$_SERVER`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), to find what was the request.

For example, if I call this URL :

```
http://tests/temp/strange.php?plop=1
```

And use this portion of code in my `temp.php` :

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

I get this output :

```
array
  ...
  'SERVER_NAME' => string 'tests' (length=5)
  'SERVER_ADDR' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'SERVER_PORT' => string '80' (length=2)
  ...
  'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING' => string 'plop=1' (length=6)
  'REDIRECT_URL' => string '/temp/strange.php' (length=17)
  ...
  'QUERY_STRING' => string 'plop=1' (length=6)
  'REQUEST_URI' => string '/temp/strange.php?plop=1' (length=24)
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/temp/temp.php' (length=14)
  ...
```

So, here, I guess I could re-build the file-name, using **`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`**.

Comment: @Molfar : oh, too bad. I've edited my answer with some additional info ; hope this helps !